# How to subclass Windows Common Controls?

Tags: c, user-interface, winapi, subclassing

I have a problem.
I subclass my TreeView like this:

```
SetWindowSubclass(hTV, SubClassProc, 0, 0);
```

where hTv - handle to WC_TREEVIEW window produced by CreateWindowEx.
This is my SubClassProc:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK    SubClassProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam,
                                 LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case TVM_EXPAND:
        // This line of code is never executed
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("I'm expanded"), _T("TreeView"), MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        break;
    case WM_NCDESTROY:
        RemoveWindowSubclass(hWnd, SubClassProc, uIdSubclass);
        break;
    }

    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Why can't I handle TVM_EXPAND message? What's wrong in my code?

I uploaded my project [here](http://www.ex.ua/311517527708).

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, but I guess you're wondering why you don't see `TVM_EXPAND` when you click on a + sign to expand a branch of the tree. It's because the tree doesn't send `TVM_EXPAND` to itself. If you want to trap *all* expansions then you need to sub-class the tree's **parent** and watch for `TVN_ITEMEXPANDING` notification messages.

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna try it. But who else could receive `TVM_EXPAND` unless the treeview control? If I'm a sender (or whoever else), someone must handle this message.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter, format your comment as an answer, please. Technically, it works fine. But what about semantics? Now, I'm still an independent control, but *my* parent doesn't seem to be so. What if anyone else called `SetWindowSubclass` after/before me? What would happen then?

Comment: `SetWindowSubclass` handles that for you, no need to worry.

Comment: I have tried to handle all other cases when tree expands/collapses a node, as user *IInspectable* pointed out but it was just too much. I would **strongly** suggest you to do things the way other answer suggested -> via notification messages. I have deleted my answer in order not to mislead other readers who have the same problem. If you still wish to proceed "my way" leave a comment and I will undelete the answer. Best regards.

Comment: I think the easiest solution is the @JonathanPotter's one. Actually, I still don't understand why the parent does handle notification and the treeview control doesn't handle message (directly through the redefined procedure). Anyway, thank you. I'm going to try it.

Comment: @JohnSmith `TVM_EXPAND` lets the app control the tree expansion. But clicking on the + sign is handled completely internally by the tree control. Think of them as two completely separate code paths (`TVM_EXPAND` handler, and `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` handler) that both call an internal `ExpandTreeItem()` function.

Comment: Instead of editing your question to say "SOLVED", accept an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is handled in main window procedure. There is no need for subclass in this case.

Check for **`TVN_ITEMEXPANDED`**, this is a notification received when item is expanded. Send `TVM_EXPAND` message if you want to expand the item.

See also:
- [TreeView send **M**essages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff486106%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (example: `TVM_EXPAND`)
- [TreeView receive **N**otifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff486107%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (example: `TVN_ITEMEXPANDED`)

```
BOOL CALLBACK mainProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {

    case WM_NOTIFY:
    {
        LPNMHDR hdr = (LPNMHDR)lParam;
        if (hdr->hwndFrom == hWndTree && hdr->code == TVN_ITEMEXPANDED)
        {
            MessageBox(hwnd, _T("I'm expanded"), _T("TreeView"), MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
    ...    
}
```

Comment: If only it was so easy, I wouldn't post this thread. There's one thing. I need to get absolutely independent control. I have no access to the main window procedure. I just need to modify standard behavior. And subclassing is the only way I have.

Comment: According to MSDN *TVN_ITEMEXPANDING notifies a tree-view control's parent window...* and the TVM_EXPAND might be sent to control.

Comment: You need to subclass the TreeView's parent window to intercept `TVN_...`notifications sent from the TreeView. `TVM_...` messages are not notifications, they are messages sent to the TreeView to perform actions and query data.  You can use `SetWindowSubclass(GetParent(hTV), ...)` to subclass the parent window.

Comment: You can wrap the control. Create your own window that is the parent of the tree view, and have your clients create your parent control. This is a standard technique.

Comment: This is usage of `TVM_EXPAND`: `SendMessage(hTree, TVM_EXPAND, TVE_TOGGLE, (LPARAM)hItem);` This message is not generated by Windows or TreeView. You send it yourself (programmatically) to expand/collapse the tree item, it can be caught in TreeView's subclass. For user input however, TreeView will process input and make `TVN_X` messages for parent window. Deal with `TVN_ITEMEXPANDED` first. Later you can test sending `TVM_EXPAND` to make sure that part works too. I think `TVM_EXPAND` will generate `TVN_ITEMEXPANDED` message for parent, but it does that only once. See also `TVIS_EXPANDEDONCE`